# Разметка html5 страницы каталога товаров

Tags: html, html5, seo, разметка

Доброго времени суток. С выходом HTML5 появилось множество различных дополнительных тегов и многое другое. А я хочу использовать их правильно и как следует. Изучил несколько статей в интернете ([для примера](https://habrahabr.ru/post/124993/)). Но хочу на всякий случай уточнить некоторые нюансы.

Планируется страница, которая выводит список товаров определённой категории. На странице будет: главное меню для навигации по сайту, сайтбар с фильтрами, карточки товаров. Разметку в общем виде я себе представляю следующим образом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>Основная навигация по всему сайту</nav>
        <main>
            <h1>Название категории товара</h1>
            <aside>Фильтр</aside>
            <h2>Название товара</h2>
            <h2>Название товара</h2>
            <h2>Название товара</h2>
            <h2>Название товара</h2>
            <h2>Название товара</h2>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Насчёт тега `<main>` у меня сомнения. Быть может стоит выбрать `<article>` (`<content>` устарел)? Что касается карточке товаров, то они все в отдельных дивах и т.п. - их я опустил для наглядности.

Если поместить код в [HTML 5 Outliner](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/), то окажется, что `<nav>`, которая не входит в `<main>` учитывается в структуре и должна иметь заголовок (т.к. его нет, то отображается как `Untitled Section`). С `<aside>` схожая ситуация - должен иметь заголовок. Т.е. поскольку они должны иметь заголовки, эти блоки как-то учитываются? И быть может их заменить на обычные div? Или что-то ещё?

Отсюда вытекают вопросы: правильно ли я выбрал способ разметки документа для страницы с карточками товаров? Верный ли порядок представления информации? Использую ли я правильные теги для разметки? Как быть с заголовками у `<nav>` и `<aside>`? Как это вообще всё сказывается на SEO и т.п. и т.д.? Есть быть может какие-то дополнительные рекомендации?

Особняком стоит вопрос микроразметки каждого товара. Сейчас в самом приоритете ( если не ошибаюсь) [JSON for Linking Data](http://json-ld.org/). Есть, конечно, [schema.org](http://schema.org/), но вроде как тот же гугл уже отдаёт предпочтение не этой технологии, а JSON for Linking Data. Оно и ясно - [намного удобнее работать](https://texterra.ru/blog/chto-takoe-format-json-ld-i-pochemu-on-luchshe-schema-org.html). Кто нибудь работал с этой технологией в ключе описания страницы с карточками товаров, а не одного отдельного товара?

**upd.** В итоге пришёл к структуре документа вида:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>Основная навигация по всему сайту</nav>
        <aside>Фильтр</aside>
        <article>
            <h1>Название категории товара</h1>
            <section><h2>Название товара</h2></section>
            <section><h2>Название товара</h2></section>
            <section><h2>Название товара</h2></section>
            <section><h2>Название товара</h2></section>
            <section><h2>Название товара</h2></section>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

**upd2.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Сайт</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Название сайта</h1>
            <nav><h2>Навигация по сайту</h2></nav>
        </header>
        <article>
            <h2>Название категории товара 1</h2>
            <aside><h3>Фильтр</h3></aside>
            <section><h3>Название товара 1</h3></section>
            <section><h3>Название товара 2</h3></section>
            <section><h3>Название товара 3</h3></section>
            <section><h3>Название товара 4</h3></section>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Имеет вид:
[image: вид]

Однако вопросы всё ещё актуальны. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Посмотрите на вашу последнюю структуру. В ней Навигация по сайту является второй по значению величиной, на которую вы обращаете внимание поисковика и браузера. Моё мнение, что навигацию вообще не надо обозначать элементами h. Ей хватит и структурированной разметки. По моему мнению, в последней вашей структуре главная тема страницы - это Категория товара, но не навигация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я рекомендую вам следующий исходный код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <main>
       <h1>Название магазина/сайта</h1>        
       <nav>Основная навигация по всему сайту</nav>
            <h2>Название категории товара</h2>
            <aside>Фильтр</aside>
            <h3>Название товара</h3>
            <h3>Название товара</h3>
            <h3>Название товара</h3>
            <h3>Название товара</h3>
            <h3>Название товара</h3>
       </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Здесь иерархия идёт вниз от названия магазина.сайта. Данная структура сообщает, что указанная категория товара и все наименования товара являются частью данного магазина/сайта. Не забывайте, что из элементов h поисковики берут информацию, так называемого Длинного Хвоста. **[Спецификация элемента main](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp)**:

> The  tag specifies the main content of a document - Тег <главная> определяет основное содержание документа

Здесь нет четкого требования для этого элемента. Я считаю, что ваше главной содержание указано в этом элементе, но и ваш вариант не является ошибкой. Этот элемент должен применяться на странице только в единственном экземпляре. Элементы article и section могут применяться многократно. Все эти элементы являются **[семантическими элементами стандарта ХТМЛ5](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)**. С ними вы можете фрагментировать/сегментировать исходный код страниц. Кроме указанного вами HTML 5 Outliner, вы можете применять **[валидатор W3](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)**, с выбором фильтра outline. Результат смотрите внизу в секциях Heading-level outline и Structural outline. На мой взгляд этот инструмент даёт более четкую визуализацию структуры страницы. Для списка товаров, я рекомендую вам применять структурированную разметку **[OfferCatalog](https://schema.org/OfferCatalog)**. Внизу вы можете видеть примеры этой разметки во всех применяемых формах. Этая разметка является дочерней/уточняющей разметкой **ItemList**.

Comment: Навигация не является частью уникального контента страницы, следовательно не должна находиться в main.

Comment: Изучил ваши рекомендации и пришёл к новому решению для себя (смотрите мой вопрос - upd2). В итоге чётко прослеживается иерархия вниз от названия магазина. В валидаторах все пункты имеют свои названия и т.п. (рисунок выше). Что думаете?

Comment: Насчёт микроразметки. А как вы смотрите на  JSON for Linking Data?

Comment: Применение JSON for Linking Data зависит от вашей аудитории, т.к. она не поддерживается Yahoo + Bing (кажется), но эти поисковики имеют примерно 80% в Британии и чуть более 50% в Германии. Кроме того, если в структурированную разметку устанавливать большие объёмы данных, то с применением JSON придётся дублировать это. А это утяжеляет и тормозит загрузку страницы. Но Гугл всячески это продвигает.

Comment: В спецификации W3 не указано, что main содержит уникальное содержание, но основное содержание. Здесь я вижу различие.